# AddRange throwing null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a function called GetSuggestedAddresses and there's is a piece of it which calls a function that returns a List. I also have a property in my class that is type List. I tried using AddRange to add in my returned results to my property but it is throwing a null exception. I tried stepping through the code but I'm a bit lost. Any ideas? Here is my code-

```
 public List<ExpressAddressResult> GetSuggestedAddresses(string format = "xml")
  {
     foreach (RequestArrayRecord address in reqRecords) {
        string result = string.Empty;
        NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
        collection.Add("id", AuthKey);
        collection.Add("line1", CleanUpAddress(address.AddressLine1));
        collection.Add("city", address.City);
        collection.Add("state", address.State);
        collection.Add("postalcode", address.Zip);
        collection.Add("maxrecords", MaxSuggestionResults.ToString());
        collection.Add("format", format);
        string parameters = GenerateParameters(collection);

        Uri serviceAddress = new Uri(RequestURL + parameters);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceAddress);
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
           if (response != null) {
              using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
                 result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
              }
           }
        }

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(result);

        List<ExpressAddressResult> results = CreateListFromXml(xmlDoc);

        if (results != null) {
           AddressSuggestions.AddRange(results); // Throws Null Exception
        }
     }

     return AddressSuggestions; // This is a property of type List<ExpressAddressResult>
  }
```

Comment: Where is `AddressSuggestions` defined? Have you verified that it is not null?

Comment: Well, if I was to guess... `AddressSuggestions` is null.  Have you stepped through this or inspected the variables when it breaks on the exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @RichardEverett AddressSuggestions is a property defined in my class. It is just public List<ExpressAddressResult> AddressSuggestions {get; set;}

Comment: @CharlesMager Yes I've stepped through the code. Do I need to initialize my list before I add anything to it? I think that's where I might have messed up.

Comment: @KrazyDev yep, you need initialize it before using.

Comment: Yes. You should do it on your constructor to avoid checking null everywhere :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var addressSuggestions = new List<ExpressAddressResult>();
```

Though  I think you just want to return results.. It's been converted into the expected type. *forget the addRange*

Comment: Yup! This was it! I forgot to initialize this in my constructor. Didn't realize that I had to initialize the List beforehand.

Comment: Cool glad you got it working, so AddressSuggestions is the list the drop down is binding to and it wasn't initialised.

Answer (score 1):

The list to which you are actually adding the range is null, i.e. `AddressSuggestions` is null.

So make sure `AddressSuggestions` is initialized before you are adding any items to this list.